# Execute autocommand only if buffer contains a pattern

Tags: buffers, autocmd, plugin-ultisnips

Concrete example:

When using React with Styled Components, I want to load the CSS snippets file. I could achieve this with:

```
autocmd FileType javascript,typescript :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes css
```

However, I'd like to execute the command above only if `styled-components` is included in the current buffer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the check in a function so it’s not a mess:

```
function react#add_snips() abort
  if search('styled-components', 'nw') != 0
    UltiSnipsAddFiletypes css
  endif
endfunction
```

(This can go in `~/.vim/autoload/react.vim`)

And then call the function:

```
augroup react
  autocmd!
  autocmd Filetype javascript,typescript call react#add_snips
augroup END
```

Alternatively, place the `call` portion in both `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` and `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/typescript.vim`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, @D. Ben Knoble